'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Provided owner is not allowed'
I have a solana program which has the following function in it.
pub fn create_vault(ctx: Context<CreateVault>) -> Result<()> {
        let program_state = &mut ctx.accounts.program_state;

        // Ensure only the owner can initialize the vault
        require!(
            ctx.accounts.owner.key() == program_state.owner,
            ErrorCode::Unauthorized
        );

        // Check if the vault has already been initialized
        require!(
            !program_state.vault_initialized,
            ErrorCode::VaultAlreadyInitialized
        );

        // Ensure that the vault is created successfully under program control (PDA)
        msg!("Initializing USDC Vault...");

        // Create an associated token account for the program's PDA (vault) to hold USDC
        let cpi_accounts = anchor_spl::associated_token::Create {
            payer: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            associated_token: ctx.accounts.vault_usdc_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.vault_authority.to_account_info(),
            mint: ctx.accounts.usdc_mint.to_account_info(),
            system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            token_program: ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
        };

        // Use invoke_signed to add the PDA's authority via seeds and bump
        let (_vault_authority, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"vault"], ctx.program_id);
        let seeds = &[b"vault".as_ref(), &[bump]];
        let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
            cpi_accounts,
            signer_seeds,
        );
        anchor_spl::associated_token::create(cpi_ctx)?;

        // Mark the vault as initialized
        program_state.vault_initialized = true;
        msg!("USDC Vault created successfully.");

        Ok(())
    }

The function is supposed to create a vault which will hold USDC for the program, and be controlled by the program.
I have the following script other to call this function on the deployed function.
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, AnchorProvider, setProvider, web3 } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { CumulusDelta } from "../target/types/cumulus_delta"; // Import the generated types for the program
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-base";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import {
    getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount,
    createAssociatedTokenAccount,
    getAssociatedTokenAddress,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

(async () => {
    // Step 1: Configure the connection
    const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet; // Set the network to devnet
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl(network), "confirmed");
    console.log("connnection is:", connection)

    // Step 2: Set up the wallet (use your local wallet or a keypair)
    const wallet = anchor.Wallet.local() // This assumes you're using a local keypair (from ~/.config/solana/id.json)
    console.log("wallet is: ", wallet)
    // Step 3: Create an AnchorProvider and set it globally
    const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {});
    setProvider(provider);

    // Step 4: Load the program's IDL and program ID
    const idl = JSON.parse(readFileSync("../target/idl/cumulus_delta.json", "utf8"));

    // Step 5: Initialize the program object
    const program = new Program(idl as CumulusDelta);
    console.log("program id is: ", program.programId)
    // PDA for vault authority
    const [vaultAuthority, vaultAuthorityBump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [Buffer.from("vault")], // "vault" is the seed
        program.programId
    );
    console.log("vault authority is: ",vaultAuthority)
    // Get the USDC mint address (use the correct one for Devnet or Mainnet)
    const usdcMint = new web3.PublicKey("4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU"); // Devnet USDC Mint

    // Create or get the associated token account for the vault (USDC token account)
    // Step 4: Get or create the vault's USDC account (initialize it if necessary)
    const vaultUsdcAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        provider.connection,               // Solana connection object
        wallet.payer,                      // The payer's keypair
        usdcMint,                          // The USDC mint
        vaultAuthority,                    // The PDA (vault authority) that controls the vault account
        true                               // Allow account creation if it doesn't exist
    );

    console.log("Vault USDC account created:", vaultUsdcAccount.address.toBase58());

    // Step 8: Call the initializeProgram method
    try {
        const tx_va = await program.methods
            .createVault() // Call the method
            .accounts({
                payer: wallet.publicKey,               // The wallet that pays for the transaction
                vaultUsdcAccount: vaultUsdcAccount.address,    // The vault's associated USDC account
                usdcMint: usdcMint,                    // The USDC mint
                programState: new web3.PublicKey("A7JrKeg6AgX4k8kvCUzmZwxVZHULAMsFSVAfzezLosN7"), // Replace with the actual program state public key
                owner: provider.wallet.publicKey, // Owner of the program (likely the wallet)
            })
            .rpc();

        console.log("Vault created successfully, transaction signature:", tx_va);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error initializing the vault:", error);

        if (error.logs) {
            console.error("Transaction logs:", error.logs);
        }
    }
})();


However when I call the script I get this error.
 transactionMessage: 'Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Provided owner is not allowed',
  transactionLogs: [
    'Program 5jE1aX2LEh67SAoNYMDL7yDSNoiYPPXKKkMFRCLkbvBG invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: CreateVault',
    'Program log: Initializing USDC Vault...',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Create',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 5058 of 180736 compute units',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided owner is not allowed',
    'Program 5jE1aX2LEh67SAoNYMDL7yDSNoiYPPXKKkMFRCLkbvBG consumed 24322 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program 5jE1aX2LEh67SAoNYMDL7yDSNoiYPPXKKkMFRCLkbvBG failed: Provided owner is not allowed'
  ],
  programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack {
    stack: [
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(5jE1aX2LEh67SAoNYMDL7yDSNoiYPPXKKkMFRCLkbvBG)]],
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL)]]
    ]
  }
}
Transaction logs: [
  'Program 5jE1aX2LEh67SAoNYMDL7yDSNoiYPPXKKkMFRCLkbvBG invoke [1]',
  'Program log: Instruction: CreateVault',
  'Program log: Initializing USDC Vault...',
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [2]',
  'Program log: Create',
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 5058 of 180736 compute units',
  'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided owner is not allowed',
  'Program 5jE1aX2LEh67SAoNYMDL7yDSNoiYPPXKKkMFRCLkbvBG consumed 24322 of 200000 compute units',
  'Program 5jE1aX2LEh67SAoNYMDL7yDSNoiYPPXKKkMFRCLkbvBG failed: Provided owner is not allowed'
]

The program is deployed on devnet.
Any ideas how to fix this?

It looks like your code is initializing the associated-token-account for the vault twice: once using getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, and then a second time in your program. Since the account already exists, feel free to just remove the code that creates the token account in your program!
Instead, you'll need to make sure that the token account is owned by your vault PDA and for the USDC mint.
